# How do I share link on friends wall with latest Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm developing an iOS application that heavily relies on Facebook SDK. Before [Facebook API february breaking changes](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/) I could successfully share links/text on my friends wall even if they didn't have my application installed/allowed. 
I used FB graph path for this: https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed. Since now it's impossible I tried notifications API, event creation and user tagging. 
User tagging didn't work, nor is it possible to send notifications to people without my application and event creation looks ugly and bad for marketing reasons. And what is the best way to give people opportunity to share links on their friends wall?